# Why does $L$ have to be lower triangular in the LU factorization?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, gaussian-elimination

I was studying LU factorization, when I didn't understand a particular phrase, or rather, how it works or why it works.

During LU factorization L is said to be a lower triangular matrix and U is said to be an upper triangular matrix, for **A=LU**.

All my book says is: "Suppose A can be reduced to an echelon form U using only row replacements that add a
multiple of one row to another row below it. In this case, there exist unit lower triangular
elementary matrices $E_1, E_2..... E_p$ such that
$$
E_p....E_1A=U.
$$
Then
$$
A = (E_p...E_1)^{-1}U=LU,
$$
where
$$
L=(E_p...E_1)^{-1}.
$$
All the book says is the *unit lower triangular matrix exists* not mentioning why it exists or how it exists. A substantial amount of theory missing here. Could anyone please explain this?

Comment: Making a "row replacement that adds a multiple of one row to another row below it" means multiplying a unit lower triangular matrix from the left. Check it out.

Comment: @amsmath , row replacement that adds a multiple of one row to another row below it" means multiplying a unit lower triangular matrix from the left. Check it out" !! where am I supposed to do that? Any particular sources, explanations? If I knew why would I be asking here?

Comment: I wrote "Check it out". This is a trivial task. Just take a 2x2 matrix and manipulate it as stated. Then try to multiply a matrix from the left to get the same result.

Comment: @amsmath, I have actually done that but rather unsatisfied, like if there was some kind of a general derivation or something, could've been concrete. Rather than verifying the result..... if it laid the foundations, would be more concrete

Comment: Your question seems very peculiar.  The "L" in "LU decomposition" stands for "lower triangular" and the "U" for "upper triangular".  The "LU decomposition"  of matrix A is **defined** as "finding a lower triangular matrix, L, and an upper triangular matrix, U, such that A= LU".  The L has to be lower triangular by **definition**.

Comment: First: Pose your questions in an understandable form. Second: This is not a homework solution board and it's not *our job* to answer your questions. I have to leave now. When I come back and there should not be an answer, I will write one.

Comment: @amsmath, the question is quite clear, its not my homework, its conceptual, and when did i so its anyones job? But the full forms of LU being an explanation is quite not satisfactory. And there might be some one else who'd think that this is a normal question,

Comment: @amsmath, There's no point telling me that I'm telling you it's not your job, everyone knows that.

Comment: Alright, then we agree. Now, you can have a look at my answer.

Comment: I'm confused at how my answer doesn't help. It is literally from a graduate level textbook on the subject.

Comment: @RHowe, I think it's because you're showing us how to do LU factorization, which we already know. The question is why L is a lower triangular matrix? And, it also might be downvoted because, you're not using mathjax formatting and pasting pictures.(I've been too, because the *exchange the community is thinking about getting things right.)

Comment: the more specific reason is below. if you knew how to do an LU factorization you'd know that perhaps...the individual matrices are never constructed..

Comment: I actually know how to do that

Comment: @RHowe The question was not how to do $LU$ factorization. Clearly, the answer to OP's question is in there, but you posted all too much in my opinion.

Comment: @amsmath if you actually read the paragraph it notes that how the $\ell_{jk}$   zeros out the rows and constructs the matrix $U$ making it upper triangular. The matrix  $L$ was an identity matrix and they are only putting these factors $\ell_{jk}$ beneath because the loop starts at $k=2,j=1$.

Comment: @RHowe I know how $LU$ factorization works, thank you. I've just held a lecture containing this topic last semester. You should better read my comment (much less text than your answer) which says "Clearly, the answer to OP's question is in there (i.e., in your answer)".

Answer (score 2):

Let's add the first row $a_1$ of $A$, multiplied by $c\in\Bbb R$, to the $k$-th row $a_k$. That is,
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}a_1\\\vdots\\a_k\\\vdots\\a_n\end{pmatrix}
$$
becomes
$$
A' = \begin{pmatrix}a_1\\\vdots\\ca_1+a_k\\\vdots\\a_n\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1 & & & & \\ & \ddots & & & \\c & & 1 & & \\ & & &\ddots & \\ & & & & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a_1\\\vdots\\a_k\\\vdots\\a_n\end{pmatrix} = LA,
$$
where in $L$ every blank space is a zero. That's all.

Comment: I've not done this for a 2X2 matrix A, do you think you could add an example for that?

Comment: and I think there's more to it than this, as to why an upper triangular matrix works

Comment: @bzal "I've not done this for a 2X2 matrix A, do you think you could add an example for that?" Dude, just put in numbers for $a_1$ and $a_2$. Then you have an example.

Comment: I've made it more complicated for you so that it's not only for 2x2 matrices. And who the heck downvoted my answer? It answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a slightly different LU decomposition called the Cholesky decomposition that creates two upper triangular matrices. The reason primarily is how it constructs the matrices. Gaussian elimination is simple to illustrate and I will show you. I recommend Trefethan and Bau personally.

Gaussian Elimination without Pivoting is as follows. The primary purpose of Gaussian elimination, if you follow this, is to find $\ell_{jk}$ which zeros out the row below. That is why it is the ratio of the two rows and then you subtract them. This continues on and on. Why does it have to be lower triangular? Because that is an identity matrix and it is only entering below the diagonal.

[image]

Suppose that

$$ A  = \begin{bmatrix} 1 &  1 & 1 \\ 3 & 5 & 6 \\ -2 & 2 & 7  \end{bmatrix} $$
$$ A = LU $$

$$ U =A, L=I$$
$$ k=1,m=3,j=2$$
$$\ell_{21} = \frac{u_{21}}{u_{11}}  = \frac{a_{21}}{a_{11}} = 3 $$
$$ u_{2,1:3} = u_{2,1:3} - 3 \cdot u_{1,1:3}  $$
Then we're going to subtract 3 times the 1st row from the 2nd row
$$ \begin{bmatrix} 3 & 5 & 6 \end{bmatrix} - 3 \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 2 & 3\end{bmatrix}  $$
Updating each of them
$$U = \begin{bmatrix} 1 &  1  & 1 \\ 0 & 2 & 3 \\ -2 & 2 & 7 \end{bmatrix} $$
$$ L =\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 3 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} $$
$$k=1,j=3,m=3 $$
$$\ell_{31} = \frac{u_{31}}{u_{11}} = \frac{-2}{1} = -2 $$
$$ u_{3,1:3} = u_{3,1:3} +2 \cdot u_{1,1:3} $$
Then we add two times the first row to the third row
$$ \begin{bmatrix} -2 & 2 & 7 \end{bmatrix} +  2 \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1& 1  \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 4 & 9  \end{bmatrix} $$
Updating 
$$ U = \begin{bmatrix} 1 &  1  & 1 \\ 0 & 2 & 3 \\ 0 & 4 & 9 \end{bmatrix}  $$
$$ L =\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 3 & 1 & 0 \\ -2 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} $$
$$ k=2, j=3,m=3 $$
$$ \ell_{32} = \frac{u_{32}}{u_{22}} = \frac{4}{2} = 2$$
We're subtracting out little blocks
$$ u_{3,2:3} = u_{3,2:3} - 2 \cdot u_{2,2:3} $$
$$ \begin{bmatrix} 4 & 9 \end{bmatrix} - 2 \cdot\begin{bmatrix} 2& 3 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 3 \end{bmatrix} $$
Updating 
$$ U = \begin{bmatrix} 1 &  1  & 1 \\ 0 & 2 & 3 \\ 0 & 0 & 3 \end{bmatrix}  $$
$$ L =\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 3 & 1 & 0 \\ -2 & 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix} $$
It now terminates
$$ A  = LU $$
$$ \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix} 1 &  1 & 1 \\ 3 & 5 & 6 \\ -2 & 2 & 7  \end{bmatrix}}_{A} = \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 3 & 1 & 0 \\ -2 & 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}}_{L} \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix} 1 &  1  & 1 \\ 0 & 2 & 3 \\ 0 & 0 & 3 \end{bmatrix}}_{U}   $$

A more specific reason is the generalization of how this works
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> using only row replacements that add a multiple of one row to another row below it

This operation expressed as elementary matrix $E$ is a lower triangular matrix in this case ("to another row *below* it", $j > i$).

E.g. see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix#Row-addition_transformations) for how $E=L_{i,j}(m)$ looks like (identity matrix plus $m$ entry in row $j$, column $i$), which adds the $m$-th multiple of row $i$ to row $j$ if applied from the left to some matrix $A$. ($R_j' = R_j + m R_i$)

The inverse operation $E^{-1}$ is subtracting the $m$-th multiple of row $i$ to row $j$. ($R_j' = R_j - m R_i$), which is $L_{i,j}(-m)$. So the inverse is an elementary matrix as well, and a lower triangular matrix as well.

$L$ consists of the product of lower triangular matrices,
$$
L = (E_p \dotsb E_1)^{-1} = E_1^{-1} \dotsb E_p^{-1}
$$
so it is a lower triangular matrix as well.