# Let $A$ be a matrix with echelon form $U_n=E_n\cdots E_1A$ produced without row interchanges. Show $E_j$ is lower triangular.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A$ be a matrix with echelon form $U_n=E_n\cdots E_1A$ produced without row interchanges. Show $E_j$ is lower triangular.

More specifically,  $U_j$ is the intermediate form between $A$ and $U_n$ that has $j$-many pivot columns. Then $E_j$ is clearly a matrix that zeroes all entries below the $j$th pivot, and $E_j$ is clearly lower triangular (recall the corresponding elementary matrix for adding a multiple of a row to another). But I'm having a hard time making a rigorous proof for this.

I'm seeing that this is probably some sort of induction proof, so I've been working on the $E_1A = U_1$ case. But I'm having trouble even with this first case, so I've decided to prove a single simple case, where $E_1A$ is a $4 \times 4$ matrix with entries of only either 1 or 0. Then, the possible values of $U_1$ are:

[image]

This at least seems to suggest a vague angle of attack, since there clearly seems to be an algorithmic way to define $U_j$. For the simplified $U_1$ case above, we clearly see that $E_1$ has to be lower triangular. But, how can we start making an abstract proof on the basis of what we've done?

Would anyone have tips on how to move forward from here?

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2877109/why-does-l-have-to-be-lower-triangular-in-the-lu-factorization?rq=1 
however, it doesn't help us in this proof

Comment: For such a sequence of row operations, we would have to add multiples of upper rows to lower rows. Does this say anything about the structure of $E_i$?

Comment: @UmeshShankar yes absolutely, it clearly indicates $E_i$ will be lower diagonal, if we recall the form of the elementary matrix corresponding to adding a multiple of a row to another. the problem of course is, how do we formalize such a proof, even for just $E_1$, for an arbitrary $n \times n$ matrix?